# Deploying SWIG dependent dll's with Android Application

Tags: android, swig

I would like to use a .jar file generated by SWIG in an Android application.  What is the best way to deploy all of the underlying dll's with the Android application?

In a desktop environment, my PATH variable includes the folder containing these dll's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DLL is a Windows technology. Android is not Windows. Android is based on Linux. You would be looking for `.so` libraries. More accurately, you will be looking for the C/C++ source code behind those libraries, so you can cross-compile them for Android chipsets (e.g., ARM). That will be accomplished via the [Native Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html).